# Ошибка в написании кода для дискорд бота

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-api

[image: ошибка]

Я хочу чтоб в моём эмбэде упоминались победители, но оно просто игнорируется. Что делать?

```py
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Розыгрыш!", description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.author.color)

    embed.add_field(name = "Создал(а):", value = ctx.author.mention)
    
    embed.set_footer(text = f"Закончится через {answers[1]}")

    my_msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)


    await my_msg.add_reaction("")

    seconds = convert(answers[1])
    number_of_winners = int(answers[3])
    while seconds > -1:

        embed1 = discord.Embed(title = "Розыгрыш!", description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.author.color)

        embed1.add_field(name = "Создал(а):", value = ctx.author.mention)
    
        embed1.set_footer(text = f"Закончится через {seconds}")
 
        await my_msg.edit(embed=embed1)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        seconds -= 1

    print(seconds)

    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))

    if number_of_winners == 1:
        winner = random.choice(users).mention
        await channel.send(f"Поздравляю! {winner} выиграл {prize}!")
    elif seconds == 0: 

        embed2 = discord.Embed(title = "Розыгрыш!", description = f"Победитель: {winner}\n", color = ctx.author.color)

        embed2.add_field(name = "Создал(а):", value = ctx.author.mention)
    
        embed2.set_footer(text = f"Закончился!")

        await my_msg.edit(embed1=embed2)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    else:
        winners = []
        while number_of_winners != 0: #Выполнять блок кода, пока number_of_winners не будет равен 0
            winner = random.choice(users).mention #Получаем рандомного победителя
            if winner in winners:
                continue 
            else: #Если нету то
                winners.append(winner) #Добавляем его в победители
                number_of_winners -= 1 #Отнимаем от количества победителей 1
                winners = '\n'.join(winners)
    if seconds == 0:

        embed3 = discord.Embed(title = "Розыгрыш!", description = f"Winners: {winners}\n", color = ctx.author.color)

        embed3.add_field(name = "Создал(а):", value = ctx.author.mention)

        embed3.set_footer(text = f"Закончился!")

        await my_msg.edit(embed2=embed3)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    else:
        winners = []
        while number_of_winners != 0: #Выполнять блок кода, пока number_of_winners не будет равен 0
            winner = random.choice(users).mention #Получаем рандомного победителя
            if winner in winners:
                continue 
            else: #Если нету то
                winners.append(winner) #Добавляем его в победители
                number_of_winners -= 1 #Отнимаем от количества победителей 1
                winners = ', '.join(winners)
                await channel.send(f"Поздравляю! {winners} выиграли {prize}!")
```

Comment: Вы вообще смотрели на то, как выглядит Ваш вопрос после того, как написали его? У Вас ссылка на картинку попала в блок кода и ошибка не отображается. Специально ж для Вас, когда вопрос задаёте пишут "**проверьте Ваш вопрос**".

Comment: эта картинка никак не относится к коду, я только узнал об этом сайте и хочу понять где у меня ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно изменять уже существующий embed, и вы даже это делали: `await my_msg.edit(embed1=embed2)`

[Message.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.edit)

```
embed = discord.Embed(title = "Розыгрыш!", description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.author.color)
embed.add_field(name = "Создал(а):", value = ctx.author.mention)   
embed.set_footer(text = f"Закончится через {answers[1]}")
my_msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)

winners = []
while number_of_winners != 0: #Выполнять блок кода, пока number_of_winners не будет равен 0
    winner = random.choice(users).mention #Получаем рандомного победителя
    if winner in winners:
        continue 
    else: #Если нету то

        winners.append(winner) #Добавляем его в победители
        number_of_winners -= 1 #Отнимаем от количества победителей 1
        winners = ', '.join(winners)

        emb_win = discord.Embed(title = "Розыгрыш!", description = f"Победитель: {winner}\n", color = ctx.author.color)
        emb_win.add_field(name = "Создал(а):", value = ctx.author.mention)
        emb_win.add_field(name = "Победитель:", value = winners)
        emb_win.add_field(name = "Приз:", value = prize)
        emb_win.set_footer(text = f"Закончился!")

        await embed.edit(embed = emb_win)# изменяем первый ембед на ембед м победителем и призом
```

Comment: тоесть после  ```users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))
``` нужно вставить этот код?

Comment: теперь появилась другая проблема, когда я выбираю 2 или более победителей эмбед вписывает только 1 победителя. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'